# Generate random password with openssl_random_pseudo_bytes (PHP)

Tags: php, security, random, passwords

I use the following method to generate random password for user during password reset

```
$pass = preg_replace('/=*$/', '', base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(40)));
```

I suppose they are random enough for this purpose, right?
Are there any risk in the above method or other better ways?

Comment: This is best suited for Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since it is working code and you may get a better response.

Answer (score 0):

The function should work well to generate a random string.

Sending a password has the disavantage though, that everybody who gets a glimpse at the email can login your website. Often this is possible even after years, because the user doesn't change the password. Another thing is, that everybdoy could reset the users password, repeatedly done this would be really annoying for the user.

The usual way to solve this problem is, that you send the user a link containing a token (can be done with your function). You store the **hash** of this token in the database. If the user clicks the link and the hash of the contained token matches your database entry, the user is allowed to choose a new password himself.